# Stop Apache redirect to www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a public web site (mydomain.com) and it is up and working fine.

I am trying to setup a test domain, like dev.mysite.com.  I have a host record to resolve the IP address but the problem I can't get past is when I try to go to dev.mysite.com I am redirected to www.dev.mysite.com and that isn't working.

I tried to modify my .htaccess file, but that didn't work.  In my .htaccess file I commented out the first two lines (below) and then uncommented the last two lines, as it indicates in the .htaccess file comments, so my .htaccess file now has this:

```
 # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
 # RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Since that did not work I found another possible solution to edit my virt hosts file to include this:

```
Redirect permanent / http://dev.mysite.com/
```

After I restarted apache and try to open the site, I am getting a redirect loop now.  So am not sure what I can do to resolve this.

Comment: Look into Apache virtual domains http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: Don't you have a `UseCanonicalName` directive in apache config?

Comment: I do not have UseCanonicalName anywhere.  How would I use it in this situation?  Examples I found weren't clear.

Comment: If you have no `UseCanonicalName` directive, apache would not redirect to "www" if you didn't explicitly tell to do it. So I think, you should have a redirect to "www" in some other .htaccess, or inside httpd.conf, or inside your scripts.